# Remove the hidden characters from the string

Tags: c#, html, regex

I am trying to remove the mark up from the string like below

```
 string name = results[i].ToString();
 var b = Regex.Replace(name, "<.*?>",string.Empty);
```

String `name` looks like `&lt;div class="ExternalClassA6E"&gt;&lt;p&gt;​&lt;span&gt;GET6&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;`

When I debug I dont see any extra spl characters in the b. But when see in the application after it ran a `?` at the front of the varaiable b like ?GET6. Is there something special about the markups here?

Comment: You have posted the string value with html entities. That regexp will never match such html encoded string. Thus you either need to use entities in the regexp or your input looks different. On the other hand ? micht point to character encoding differences.

Comment: Yes, ? or � indicates to our users that we have mishandled their data and damaged it. It's great that you caught it. The problem is lack of communication or loss of control over which character encoding should be used to read text. It must be the character encoding that was used to write it.

Answer (score 3):

I copied your text above and ran some tests on it, and it is indeed acting very strangely! 
**There appears to be an actual hidden character in your string** that does not display in the editor, but does appear when the string is parsed or written to the console.

To test what you were saying, I pasted your string in my editor and ran some code, and I also saw the `?` character in the output. So then I typed the same text and ran the same tests, and there's no `?` there:

```
private static void Main()
{
    string copiedText = "&gt;​&lt;";
    string typedText  = "&gt;&lt;";

    Console.WriteLine("\nCopied Text Results\n" + "-------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("\nLength: " + copiedText.Length);
    Console.WriteLine("\nCharacters and ascii values:");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ",
        copiedText.Select(character => character + " = " + (int) character)));
    Console.WriteLine("\nString value:");
    Console.WriteLine(copiedText);
    Console.WriteLine("\nHtml Decoded value:");
    Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(copiedText));

    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + new string('-', Console.WindowWidth));

    Console.WriteLine("\nTyped Text Results\n" + "------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("\nLength: " + typedText.Length);
    Console.WriteLine("\nCharacters and ascii values:");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ",
        typedText.Select(character => character + " = " + (int) character)));
    Console.WriteLine("\nString value:");
    Console.WriteLine(typedText);
    Console.WriteLine("\nHtml Decoded value:");
    Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(typedText));

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image: ![enter image description here]

I guess this isn't really an answer, so I'll delete it shortly, but maybe it will spark someone else to provide some feedback.